# I am trying to filter trainer according to selection of checkbox by sport type , languages and age group in codeigniter and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, codeigniter

In database I have tables like:
table 1: **users**

```
id | sports_type | age_group |languages
1     1,2          1,2        1,2
2     1            1          1
```

table 2 **sports** :

```
id   name
1    Athletics
2    Aerobics
```

table 3 **languages**:

```
id   lang
1    English
2    Spanish
```

table 4 **age_group**:

```
id    groups
1     adults
2     teenagers
```

In html:

```
 <h5>sports</h5>
   <?php foreach($all_sports as $row ) { ?>
      <div class="checkbox"><label>
       <input class="sport_type" type="checkbox" name="all_sports[]" id="sport_id" value="<?php echo $row->id;?>" > &nbsp;<?php echo $row->name;?></label></div> <?php } ?>
      <h5>age groups</h5><?php foreach($age_groups as $row) { ?>
         <div class="checkbox"> 
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="age_group[]" id="age_group" value="<?php echo $row->id;?>">&nbsp; <?php echo $row->groups;?></label> 
          </div> <?php } ?> 
      <h5>languages</h5><?php foreach($languages as $row) { ?>
       <div class="checkbox"> 
       <label><input type="checkbox" name="languages[]" id="languages" value="<?php echo $row->id;?>">&nbsp;<?php echo $row->lang;?>
       </label>
      </div><?php } ?>
```

Ajax code $:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:checkbox[name="all_sports[]"]').change(function() {
    var checked = $('.sport_type:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get().join(', ');
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo site_url('show/filter_sport_data');?>",
      dataType: "text",
      data: {
        sport_id: checked
      },
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data != "") {
          $('#filter_div').html(data);
        } else {
          var add = ' <div class="coach_listing col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><h3 style="color: #0067da;">No result Found </h3></div>';
          $('#filter_div').html(add);
        }
      }
    });
  });
  $('input:checkbox[name="age_group[]"]').change(function() {
    var checked = $('#age_group:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get().join(', ');
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo site_url('show/filter_age_group');?>",
      dataType: "text",
      data: {
        age_group: checked
      },
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data != "") {
          $('#filter_div').html(data);
        } else {
          var add = ' <div class="coach_listing col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><h3 style="color: #0067da;">No result Found </h3></div>';
          $('#filter_div').html(add);
        }
      }
    });
  });
  $('input:checkbox[name="languages[]"]').change(function() {
    var checked = $('#languages:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get().join(', ');
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo site_url('show/filter_languages');?>",
      dataType: "text",
      data: {
        languages: checked
      },
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data != "") {
          $('#filter_div').html(data);
        } else {
          var add = ' <div class="coach_listing col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><h3 style="color: #0067da;">No result Found </h3></div>';
          $('#filter_div').html(add);
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

problem:
its give duplicate result. if i select sports id 1 and language 1 its fetch all sport_type and language in user table but its give two diffrent result for one user i want one result

Comment: Please say what's your issue with this code

Comment: its give duplicate result. if i select sports id 1 and  language 1  its fetch all sport_type and language in user table but its give two diffrent result for one user i want one result